# what is the meaning of this sequence function $f_n=\mathbb 1_{[n, \infty)}?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

what is the meaning of this sequence of functions $f_n=\mathbb 1_{[n, \infty)}?$

Actually after reading this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886794/557708), I got confused and didn't understand the given answer

Comment: $f_n(x)=1$ if $x \geq n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x <n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subset $S$ of some domain $X$, $\mathbf{1}_S$ usually denotes the [*indicator function of $S$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), i.e., the function
$$
\mathbf{1}_S\colon X \to \{0,1\}
$$
such that $\mathbf{1}_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$, and $0$ otherwise.

In your case, the sets considered are intervals of the form $[n,\infty)$: so, for any integer $n$, $f_n$ is the function that takes value $0$ on $(-\infty, n)$ and $1$ on $[n,\infty)$.