# why $f_n$ is decreasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given  $f_n : X \to [0,\infty)$ define by

$f_n =\begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if }\ x\in  [n,\infty) \\ 0 \ \text{if} \ x \in (-\infty,n) \end{cases}$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886794/557708) It's mention that $f_n$ is decreasing function

My question is that    why $f_n$ is decreasing function ?

My thinking : $f_n$ is neither decreasing nor increasing .$f_n$ take only value $0$ and $1$ .Therefore we can said that $f_n$ is oscillating

Comment: $f_n$ for fixed $n$ is an increasing function, but $(f_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of functions.

Comment: @projectilemotion  im not  getting $(f_n) $ meaning ?

Comment: $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions. I elaborated on my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the difference between an increasing/decreasing function and an increasing/decreasing sequence of functions. In the link you have attached, they say that the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ is decreasing. This is true, since for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ one has
$$f_n(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x).$$
However, the definition of an increasing/decreasing function $f$ is different. Namely for all $x<y$ one has for an increasing function $f(x)\leq f(y)$ and for a decreasing function $f(x)\geq f(y)$. For fixed $n$, your function $f_n$ is clearly increasing.

Comment: oks thanks u @Projectilemotion...i have  some doubt    take $ f_{n-1} =0$  and $f_n=1$ here $f_{n-1} \le f_n $ this show that $f_n$ is increasing but here $n$ is not fixed

Comment: No, you have that $f_{n-1}(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[n-1,\infty)}(x)$ and $f_n(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[n,\infty)}(x)$. For $x< n-1$, we have $f_{n-1}(x)=f_n(x)=0$, for $x\in [n-1,n)$ we have that $1=f_{n-1}(x)\geq f_n(x)=0$. Finally for $x\geq n$ we have $f_{n-1}(x)=f_n(x)=1$. Thus in each case we have that $f_{n-1}(x)\geq f_n(x)$.

Comment: okss got it now thanks u @projectilemotion