# Lebesgue theorem on monotonic convergence

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone give an example on **(0,1)** where the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem is not true for decreasing sequences of non-negative functions? I can't find such an example, does anyone know? I would be grateful..

Comment: So is it a theorem, or not true? You can't have both, unfortunately.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124033/monotone-convergence-theorem-for-non-negative-decreasing-sequence-of-measurable) may be of interest.

Comment: This clearly does not exist: Your sequence (from a certain index on) is bounded by its first integrable member. Since the functions are all nonnegative, use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: At the lecture, we defined it as a theorem, but as a task we had to find a sequence of non-negative functions for which it does not work..

Comment: The Lebegue Monotone Convergence theorem does not require the functions to have finite integral. So we cannot say that: The "sequence (from a certain index on) is bounded by its first integrable member". There might be the case that no member is integrable (have finite integral) and then we can NOT apply Lebesgue Dominate Convergence theorem.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

The Lebegue Monotone Convergence theorem does not require the functions to have finite integral. But it requires the functions to be a non-decreasing sequence.

Here is the counter-example you are looking for:

Consider the function $f_n: (0,1) \to\mathbb{R}$, defined as $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}$. Note that $\{f_n\}_n$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative functions and  $f_n \to 0$ pointwisely, but, for all $n$, $\int_{(0,1)} f_n = +\infty $ does not converge to $0$.

Here is another counter-example:

Consider the function $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$, defined as $f_n=\chi_{[n,+\infty)}$. Note that $\{f_n\}_n$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative functions and  $f_n \to 0$ pointwisely, but, for all $n$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n = +\infty $ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: @precelinam You are welcome. Thanks for upvoting my answer.  Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.