# Show that $\int |f_n-f|\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be an integrable function and $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence of non-negative measurable functions such that $f_n\to f$ and $\int_\Omega f_n\,d\mu\to \int_\Omega f\,d\mu$.
> Show that
> $
>    \int_\Omega |f_n-f|d\mu\to 0.
>   $

The naive idea of using $|\int f|\leq \int|f|$ fails because the $\leq$ sign points in the wrong directio.

This question is a follow-up to [monotone convergence for decreasing functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124033/monotone-convergence-theorem-for-non-negative-decreasing-sequence-of-measurable), so perhabs we should use that?
I think that since $f_n\to f$ we can take $|f_n-f|$ decreasing, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega |f_n-f|d\mu = \int_\Omega \lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n-f|d\mu,
$$
and perhabs what's inside vanishes.
I think this is incorrect, because we didn't use the hypothesis $\int f_n \to \int f$.
Any ideas?

Comment: It follows from Scheffé's lemma.

Comment: This can be shown using dominated convergence

Comment: Use Fatou with $f + f_n - \lvert f_n - f\rvert$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer showing two ways to prove the result (one using Dominated Convergence Theorem and the other using Fatou's lemma). Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer actualy answers your question, **accept it**, please. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question asks to prove the result:

> Let $f$ be an integrable function and $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence of non-negative measurable functions such that $f_n\to f$ (pointwise) and $\int_\Omega f_n\,d\mu\to \int_\Omega f\,d\mu$. Then $ \int_\Omega |f_n-f|d\mu\to 0$.

We are going to present two ways proofs.

**Proof** $1$. Here is a proof using Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Since $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions and $\{f_n\}$ converges to the function $f$ pointwise, we have that $f\geqslant 0$. So, since $f$ is integrable and $f\geqslant 0$, we have that $\int_\Omega f d\mu=\int_\Omega|f|d\mu<+\infty$

Now consider $f_n \wedge f$ defined by $(f_n \wedge f)(x)=\min\{f_n(x),f(x)\}$, for each $x \in \Omega$.

Since $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$,
we have that $\{f_n \wedge f\}$ converges to $f$. But we know that, for all $n$, $\vert f_n \wedge f \vert =  f_n \wedge f \leqslant f $ and   $\int_{\Omega }  f d\mu< \infty $.  So we can apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem and we have that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\Omega }  f_n \wedge f d\mu = \int_{\Omega }  f d\mu$$
To conclude the proof, note that
$$\vert f_n-f\vert = f_n+f-2(f_n\wedge f)$$
So
$$\int_{\Omega } \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu = \int_{\Omega } f_n d\mu +\int_{\Omega } f d\mu -2\int_{\Omega } (f_n\wedge f) d\mu $$
And since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\Omega }  f_n d\mu = \int_{\Omega }  f d\mu$, we have
$$  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\Omega } \vert f_n-f\vert d\mu =0$$

---

**Proof** $2$. Here is a proof using Fatou's lemma.

Since $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions and $\{f_n\}$ converges to the function $f $ pointwise, we have that $f\geqslant 0$.

Note that $|f_n -f|\leqslant f_n +f$. So, for each $n$, the function $f_n +f - |f_n -f|$ is non-negative.

Note also that, since $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f $ pointwise, we have $|f_n-f|$ converge to $0$ pointwise, and so
$ 2f= \lim (f_n+f - |f_n-f|) = \lim\inf (f_n+f - |f_n-f|)$.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega f_n d\mu = \int_\Omega f d\mu$, using Fatou's Lemma, we have:
\begin{align} 
2 \int_\Omega f d\mu 
&=\int_\Omega \lim\inf(f_n +f - |f_n -f|)d\mu \leqslant \lim\inf \int_\Omega (f_n +f - |f_n -f|)d\mu = \\ 
&=\lim\inf \left (\int_\Omega f_n d\mu +\int_\Omega f d\mu - \int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \right) = \\
&= \left(\lim\inf\int_\Omega f_n d\mu\right) +\int_\Omega f d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_\Omega |f_n -f|d\mu\right)  = \\ 
&=2\int_\Omega f d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu\right) 
\end{align}
So we have
$$2 \int_\Omega f d\mu \leqslant 2\int_\Omega f d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_\Omega |f_n -f|d\mu\right) $$
Since $f$ is integrable and $f \geqslant 0$, we know that $\int_\Omega f d\mu=\int_\Omega|f|d\mu<+\infty$, and so we get
$$\lim\sup\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \leqslant  0$$
So we can conclude that
$$\lim\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu =  0$$

Comment: I was trying to answer this question but I couldn't. May I ask (in the second proof) why is $2 \int_{\Omega} f d\mu 
=\int_\Omega \lim\inf(f_n +f - |f_n -f|)d\mu$? and why is $\lim \inf \int_{\Omega} |f_n-f|d\mu = \lim \sup \int_{\Omega} |f_n-f|d\mu$?

Comment: @UBM , For your first question, I have added more details in the proof, I have added: "Note also that, since $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f $ pointwise, we have $|f_n-f|$ converge to $0$ pointwise, and so 
$ 2f= \lim (f_n+f - |f_n-f|) = \lim\inf (f_n+f - |f_n-f|)$".

Comment: @UBM , For your second question, note that $\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu$ is a sequence of **non-negative** numbers. So, since we have proved that $\lim\sup\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \leqslant  0$, we have that $0 \leqslant  \lim\inf\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu\leqslant \lim\sup\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \leqslant  0$. So $ \lim\int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu =0$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I understand your first comment which answers my fisrt question. For your second comment, my second question was not about the end of the proof. The part I can't see is $\lim\inf \left (\int_\Omega f_n d\mu +\int_\Omega f d\mu - \int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \right) = \left(\lim\inf\int_\Omega f_n d\mu\right) +\int_\Omega f d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_\Omega |f_n -f|d\mu\right) $

Comment: the fourth equality after "....using Fatou's lemma, we have: ..."

Comment: @UBM ,  Ahh... OK.  I simply used that $ \lim\inf \left (- \int_\Omega|f_n -f|d\mu \right) = -\lim\sup\int_\Omega |f_n -f|d\mu$. 

In fact, for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers, $ \lim\inf  (- a_n) = -\lim\sup a_n$.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you so much. I would upvote twice if I could.